# Designing a web application with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web

I have a question about the design of a web application with JavaScript: Should a web application be designed to work without JavaScript, and then later add JavaScript for users that have it? Or should I design a web application with JavaScript in mind and then add fallback functionality for user that do not have JavaScript.
I hope this question makes sense. Let me know if you need me to clarify something.
Thanks.

Comment: some roads have bike lanes, while biking would be dangerous on other roads...

Comment: That depends on what your application is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms, that describe what you are looking for are "Progressive Enhancement" and "Graceful Degradation".

Here is good article describing what you already have in your question in more detail:
[A List Apart: Understanding Progressive Enhancement](http://alistapart.com/article/understandingprogressiveenhancement)

An article that could help you on your decision:
[Dev.Opera: Graceful degradation versus progressive enhancement](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/) (The named reasons are still valid, despite the fact that the article is marked as outdated)

**I favor progressive enhancement** in most cases, since it is more accessible when it comes to different output devices, software and the capabilities of the user using that website.

Answers like "there are so few people with JavaScript disabled" are just one side of the medal. Not relying on JS also could improve your site experience to non-graphical clients like search engine robots (how should they load AJAX content, when that is only accessible via JS?) or screen reader software. In fact there are many more good reasons not to rely on on JS.

Comment: Yes. This is definitely what I'm looking for. And I agree with you in that progressive enhancement is the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

At this time of age there are so few people with javascript disabled, that there is no signifcant benefit for creating a static version. Try to imagine who is your visitor and if he/she would even know how to disable it.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to design a web application with JavaScript in mind and then add fallback functionality for user that do not have JavaScript.

Now a days everything runs on JS only. You should create some kind of services/API on server side and a separate project for UI, this is the trend being followed these days.

UI project can be based on any JS framework or it can even be a simple MVC/.net project. This approach can decouple stuff, and thereafter you can create 2 UI projects one for JS users and one for the users who do not have JS.

seems a bit of a work but, it will pay in the long run.